# get comma separated list of enumeration's integers

Tags: c#

This:

```
string csvEnums = string.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(Bla)));
```

returns:

```
X1,Y1
```

given this enumeration:

```
public enum Bla
{
    [Description("X")]
    X1 = 1,
    [Description("Y")]
    Y1 = 2
}
```

Is there a similar efficient way to obtain the comma separated list:

```
1,2
```

Comment: Does not work - tried this before posting my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try casting `GetValues()` return array to `int`s:

```
string csvEnums = string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(Bla)).Cast<int>());
```

The problem with `GetValues()` method is that returns an object of type `Array`, and there are no `Join()` overload that can process it correctly.

Comment: great stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string csvEnums = string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(Bla)).Cast<Bla>().Select(x=>(int)x));
```

Comment: Tried this before posting my question. Does not work.